# Integration of graphs with datasets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Mathematica has a rich family of graph algorithms.  I would like to leverage some of these for a very large tree structure.  Because of the size of the structure, I would like to store it in a Dataset of Associations arranged in a tree structure.  My motivation is to allow the data structure to grow larger than physical memory, with a database providing primary storage.  Would it be possible to apply the graph algorithms, such as BreadthFirstScan to such a Dataset?

Comment: At this moment, Dataset is purely memory-based. This may change in the future. Why do you think it can be used for data structures larger than physical memory right now? And, as far as I know, there is no way that you can use graph functions directly on Datasets. If you're going to use data from such a Dataset for that goal you have to fully unpack it from such a Dataset and build a graph from it. Not very useful it seems.

Comment: I quote from the documentation on 10.1." The symbolic character of the Wolfram Language allows it to support an unprecedentedly flexible and general approach to structured datasets. Unifying both relational (SQL-like) and hierarchical (no-SQL) approaches, the Wolfram Language incorporates a new kind of uniquely powerful data query language\[LongDash]with seamless scaling from direct in-memory computation to computations backed by external files or databases."

Comment: Unfortunately, for now, this text only refers to database connectivity such as found with DatabaseLink. A file backed version of Dataset was mentioned/suggested in beta releases of the documentation but has not been provided yet. As far as I know, no connection has been made to Graphs, though. Graphs and Associations don't mix well as the rules in Associations have unique keys (lhs) whereas the same does not hold for the edge connectivity of Graphs.